# Disable gmail's spam filter when forwarding email?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

I have several (4-6) different Google accounts, I use the Gmail addresses for different reasons and I forward the emails from all of them to a single Gmail account.

Occasionally, important messages in these various Gmail accounts will get mistakenly sent to spam (false positives).  These messages do not get sent to my catch-all Gmail account. These false-positive messages are never critical (if they were, I'd choose to have them sent to my "main" account), but this has happened frequently enough that I wish there was a way to disable or bypass Gmail's spam filter so that **every** message comes through and the spam filtering only happens in one place.

If the spam filtering only happens in one place, I only have to check one place for false positives. Gmail's filters are excellent, but they're not perfect.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The solution to this is **not** to use Gmail's "forward a copy of incoming mail" feature, but instead to create a filter.  Filters are applied to incoming mail before spam detection takes place, giving the option to "never send to spam" in the filter rules.  The forwarding filter should use Gmail's "`deliveredto:`" operator, which handles messages that use plus addressing and messages addressed to mailing lists.

In a nutshell:

- disable forwarding if you're already using that to redirect messages to your destination address
- create a filter with the following criterion and actions

  - Has the words `deliveredto:your_incoming_address@gmail.com`
  - Forward it to `your_destination_address@example.com`
  - Never send it to spam

I have verified that this approach works.

Comment: What also works (been using it for years), is to create a filter for "label:spam" and set the action to "never send to spam". Then, all incoming spam messages will also be forwarded.

Comment: how to create a filter for "label:spam"?

Comment: Jmiserez: This sounds like  a separate answer, and maybe a cleaner one. Can you separate it out as an answer?

Comment: @jmiserez does this still work? When adding a filter like this, I see the following message: `Filter searches containing "label:", "in:", "is:", date range (e.g. "before:" or "after:") or stars criteria (e.g. "has:yellow-star") are not recommended as they will never match incoming mail. Do you still wish to continue to the next step?`

Comment: @bers, I also get the same message.

Comment: @jmiserez's answer seems to work fine; at least, I have not had any spam email in that account not forwarded any more for half a year; and I suspect that one email would have been sent to spam without the filter, because it has been forwarded, but not archived as emails usually are.